# How to fix the I/O Opperation On Closed File

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a data visualization but my file won't load. The error says "I/O operation on closed file." My first guess would be that I have an indentation error but I played around with the indentation for the "dates = []" area but the error still remains.  Thanks.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

first_date = datetime.strptime("1960", "%Y")


import csv
filename = "/Users/tgiedraitis/Downloads/API_SP.ADO.TFRT_DS2_en_csv_v2_2602143/API_SP.ADO.TFRT_DS2_en_csv_v2_2602143.csv"
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)
    
        
dates = []
for row in reader:
    dates.append(row[3])
print(dates)
    
    
fig = plt.figure(dpi = 128, figsize = (10,6))
plt.plot(dates, c="red")


plt.title("Gloval Adolescent Birthrates in 1960", fontsize = 24)
plt.xlabel("",fontsize = 16)
plt.ylabel("Average rate of birth", fontsize= 16)
plt.tick_params(axis = "both", which = "major", labelsize = 16)


    
for index, column_header in enumerate(header_row):
    print(index,column_header)
    
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the read access throughout the code by doing **f = open(filename)** to open the file and and close once you are done with your operations by doing **f.close()**.

```
filename = "filepath\filename.csv"
f = open(filename)
reader = csv.reader(f)
header_row = next(reader)

dates = []
for row in reader:
   dates.append(row[0])
print(dates)
f.close()
```

or keep the operations within **with open(filename) as f:**

```
dates = []
with open(filename) as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  header_row = next(reader)
  for row in reader:
     dates.append(row[3])
    
print(dates)
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `with`, you are telling Python to close that file once the `with` body is complete.  So you can't use `reader` outside of that block.

Answer (score 0):

When you access `reader`, you're still accessing the file internally. Therefore, if you access it after the with-statement, you'll close the internal file that `reader` is keeping and you will not be able to use it again. The solution is simple, though:

```py
import csv
filename = "/Users/tgiedraitis/Downloads/API_SP.ADO.TFRT_DS2_en_csv_v2_2602143/API_SP.ADO.TFRT_DS2_en_csv_v2_2602143.csv"
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)
    
    # Move this code into the with-statement 
    dates = []
    for row in reader:
        dates.append(row[3])
    print(dates)
    
# Keep going with your program here
fig = plt.figure(dpi = 128, figsize = (10,6))
plt.plot(dates, c="red")
```